# Command Prompt: Referencing an Executable File in a Different Folder

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

Is there any way to open a command prompt in one directory, but then reference an executable file in a different directory?

**For example:** I have `ffmpeg.exe` in folder `\x`, but I open the command prompt in folder `\y`.

**Question:** Could I reference the `ffmpeg.exe` file in folder `x` to perform its operations in folder `y`?

Comment: if the executable is not in `%PATH%` then you can always use a relative or absolute path to it while working in another directory[

Comment: It was as simple as needing to specify the full path. All set now. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reference ffmpeg in a different folder than files its commands process

- Try adding the directory which `ffmpeg.exe` resides to the [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environmental variable of the operating system, or try using the full explicit application path in the command to see if it works correctly that way (*i.e.* `C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe <params~>`).
- See if the [`ffmpeg.exe`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg) parameters allow specifying the full input and/or output file paths for whatever commands you run with the application. If this is allowed then you could simply run `CD /D "C:\Program Files\ffmpeg"` and then run the `ffmpeg.exe ~` commands with the paths of input or output commands being fully and explicitly specified.

---

### Further Resources

- [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))
- [`ffmpeg` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg)